The help center indiscriminately describes “random number generation” as on-topic
From the help center page “What topics can I ask about here?”:


Random number generation.


Yet, on a recent question:

This question is squarely off-topic on crypto.SE because it is about a non-cryptographic Random Number Generator.

I tend to agree: if the RNG doesn't at least try to be cryptographically secure, then questions about it are off-topic here.
We should tweak the wording of the help center to make it less misleading to non-cryptographers.

What about: "Cryptographically Secure (Pseudo-)Random Number Generators"? It gives the reader an opportunity to Google that, or the acronym.

I updated the help section to incorporate the proposal by fgrieu.

I suggest capitalizing each word in the current "Cryptographically Secure (Pseudo-)Random number generation", so that CS(P)RNG better stands out. Thanks anyway!

@fgrieu got it.
